# set body position lower than 30 cant be done

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d,box2d and debugDraw to draw my bodies .
i can see that if i put a vertical line(portrait) his x position can start of 50. if i set it to be 30 , it disappear from screen(retina mode)
my PTM_RATIO is set to 32 .

i put the line with :

```
const int buLX=30;
 const int buLY=10;
const int topLX=buLX;
 const int topLY=380;

//left vector
    theBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(buLX/PTM_RATIO,buLY/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(topLX/PTM_RATIO,topLY/PTM_RATIO));
    boxBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
....
```

the y coordinates are just fine, but the x has a margin from left AND from right, so i cant get to the screen edges because it disappear then.

any idea ?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

got it.

it most be a float not an integer.
because then 30/32 is 0.x which is =0 .